# EmguCV.CV.CvInvoke exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, emgucv

Good day! I am having a problem in decoding a QR Code using ZXing and Emgu CV demo particularly in the Emgu CV invoke exception issue. I can perfectly run the program with the use of my computer(the terminal in which I tested it) but after transferring the program to another computer. I get this exception.

http://i61.tinypic.com/4grexc.png

I searched the web for solutions but I can't seem to find a fitting solution.

Here's what I've tried so far:

> (1) Replace the DLLs with fresh ones from which the project contains and is referenced to.
>
> (2) Double check the assembly version (x86) for the new terminal also.

What I would like to know too:

> Should I install, download a new copy of Emgu CV libraries for the new terminal and every terminal if I were to distribute copies?

Your ideas are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to install EmguCV or OpenCV on the targeted computers, but you need to add the OpenCV dlls in your project.

1. Right-click on your project name in the Solution Explorer
2. Choose Add -> Existing Items
3. Browse to your emgufolder/bin/x86, and select all the relevant OpenCV dlls (if you're not sure which dll you need, add them all and try removing one at a time)
4. In the Solution Explorer, select all the OpenCV dlls, and in the Properties Explorer choose `Content` as a `Build Action`, and `Copy Always` as `Copy to Output Directory`.

This is my setup to deploy applications using EmguCV.